# Sinon stubs returning wrong response type

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

One of my unit tests is failing. I think it's because the stubs are returning the wrong response type. Or maybe i'm just testing the wrong thing. Here is my method

```
  let categories = Categories.create();
  let totalVideos = await Video.getTotalVideos();
  await categories.load();
  const data = categories.getData();
  if(data.length && totalVideos > 0) {
    let videoArray = [];
    for (let i = 0, categoryLength = data.length; i < categoryLength; i++) {
      let objId = data[i]._id;
      let results = await Search.findByCategoryId(objId.valueOf());
      ...
    }
    return utils.sendResponse(res, 200, utils.statusCodes.Success, {stats: videoArray});
```

And here is my test:

```
describe('GET /v1/search/videos/categories', () => {
let stub, stubVideo, stubData;

beforeEach(() => {
  req = httpMocks.createRequest({
    url: '/v1/search/videos/categories',
    method: 'GET'
  });

  stub = sinon.stub(Categories.prototype, 'load');
  stubData = sinon.stub(Categories.prototype, 'getData');
  stubVideo = sinon.stub(Video, 'getTotalVideos');
});

afterEach(() => {
  stub.restore();
  stubData.restore();
  stubVideo.restore();
});

it('should return a 200 if success', async () => {
  stub.resolves([{"_id": new ObjectId()}]);
  stubData.resolves([{"_id": new ObjectId()}, {"_id": new ObjectId()}]);
  stubVideo.resolves(10);

  expect(stubVideo).to.be.above(0);
  expect(stubData).to.have.length.above(0);

  await searchController.getAllVideosByCategory(req, res);

  expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
});
```

});

When the test runs, the assertion response for getTotalVideos is "AssertionError: expected getTotalVideos to be a number or a date". And the assertion response for getting categories array is "AssertionError: expected [Function: proxy] to have a length above 0 but got 0".

For the whole test to work,

```
videoCount > 0 && categories.length > 0
```

How do i get the stubs to return the correct response type and value to make this work?

I only added the assertions because `await searchController.getAllVideosByCategory(req, res)` keeps returning 404, meaning that for some reason the videosCount && categories.length conditions were not being met, and these assertions told me that the necessary values were not being returned to meet those conditions. So if there is another way to return those values so that the method returns 200, please let me know.

Comment: I don't see the value in either of those assertions? What is the SUT here? i.e. what is it you are trying to test. Those first 2 assertion are testing Sinon by the looks of it (and not correctly either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to understand what you want to achieve.

I found some things to improve in the codes:

1. Add `await` in `categories.getData()` source file.
2. Use `sandbox` to simplify stubbing codes
3. Add `resolves` for `Search.findByCategoryId`
4. No need to check `to.be.above` etc since you already stubbed it with the intended value.

My Code

```
describe('GET /v1/search/videos/categories', () => {
  let categoryCreateStub;
  let categoryLoadStub;
  let categoryGetDataStub;
  let getTotalVideoStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    req = httpMocks.createRequest({
      url: '/v1/search/videos/categories',
      method: 'GET'
    });

    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create(); // use sandbox for multiple stubs
    categoryLoadStub = sandbox.stub(Categories.prototype, 'load');
    categoryGetDataStub = sandbox.stub(Categories.prototype, 'getData');
    getTotalVideoStub = sandbox.stub(Video, 'getTotalVideos');
    searchFindByCategoryIdStub = sandbox.stub(Search, 'findByCategoryId');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore(); // just need to call this to restore
  });

  it('should return a 200 if success', async () => {
    categoryLoadStub.resolves([{
      "_id": new ObjectId()
    }]);
    categoryGetDataStub.resolves([{
      "_id": new ObjectId()
    }, {
      "_id": new ObjectId()
    }]);
    getTotalVideoStub.resolves(10);
    searchFindByCategoryIdStub.resolves(); // resolve this promise too! 

    await searchController.getAllVideosByCategory(req, res);

    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`expect(stubVideo).to.be.above(0)` asserts that `stubVideo` is positive number while it's a function that returns positive number. It doesn't make sense to test stubs, they are set by you. But there may be assertions that they were called:

```
expect(stubVideo).to.have.been.calledOnce;
expect(stubVideo).to.have.been.calledWith();
```

The test should spy on `utils.sendResponse` before it's called and assert that it's called with respective arguments.